# Sprockets dependencies based on ENV vars

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, sprockets

I want to be able to use an environment variable to swap out a site-specific stylesheet with sass variables to define colors for an instance of a Rails app. I can't seem to figure out how to use ruby code inside a sprockets directive to define the dependency.

What seems like it should work:

```
// stylesheets/application.css

/*
 *= require "#{ENV['SITE_STYLESHEET']}"
 *= require core
 *= require profile
 */
```

Where `ENV['SITE_STYLESHEET'] = my_stylesheet` and `stylesheets/my_stylesheet.scss` exists.`

The error I receive is: `couldn't find file '#{ENV['SITE_STYLESHEET']}'`

Is there any way to use ruby inside a directive?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but I am pretty sure would need to add an .erb extension to access the env variable

Comment: Yeah I tried that, but sprockets seems to process before ERB is.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the most eloquent way to do it, but I think you could do something like this.

1. Create initializers/assets.rb

In this file

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( ENV['SITE_STYLESHEET'] )
```